# nginx module to send a message when a server is down

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as a load balancer for few http servers (nodejs mostly). 
I was wondering if anyone here knows a module (or a way) for nginx to inform (preferably http/s but email is also ok) that one of the instances (or more) is down. I've found many modules that enable me to configure the health check behaviour, but I need something to inform me that a server is down in some way.

Comment: Rather than having nginx monitoring itself, use something like https://www.pingdom.com/

Comment: you are better using a tool to do that. What happens if nginx crashes and you don't know about it

Comment: nginx is a load balancer for other servers, nginx is checked, but the internal ones aren't. was wondering if there is an option to do so on nginx without yet another server.